# Screen Brightness for MacBook Pro 11,5 (W/ AMD R9 M370X)

Tags: 16.04, brightness, macbook, amd-graphics

I have recently triple booted with 16.04 my Macbook Pro mid-2015 that contains the dual graphics setup (AMD R9 M370X), and cannot find any information on how to get the brightness keys for the screen the work. Even within the system settings does not have a slider to adjust the brightness. Any solutions or articles to other topics that people have seen would be appreciated because many have not seemed to work for me.